# Trouble configuring local network to work with DynDns.org

Tags: router, port-forwarding, dynamic-dns

I have a Westell 7500 modem/router (two actually) from Frontier. It is setup in bridge mode, passing through to a Cisco RV042 load-balancing router. The Cisco is setup to update DynDns for my domain, and it appears to be working fine. The Cisco load balancer passes through to a Buffalo Air Station router running DD-WRT v24SP2. My PC workstation running the website is connected to the Buffalo router.

When I connect to the PC Workstation from another computer below the Buffalo Router, I am able to see the website fine. When I check my connection using the OpenPortTool, it always times out.

I have tried with all firewalls disabled. I have set the Cisco to forward all ports to the Buffalo Router, and I have set the Buffalo Router to forward all ports to the PC Workstation.

Does anyone have ideas on what could be wrong?

Here is a diagram of my network setup: [Network Diagram](https://www.lucidchart.com/documents/view/4d44-04c4-503b944d-a129-13ae0a04ef5a)

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem.

On the Buffalo router, I had set up port forwarding, but I needed to setup port range forwarding.  I had it misconfigured where I thought I was forwarding all ports to one internal IP address, but I was actually forwarding port #1 from the external to port #65535 on the internal address.

My bad.

As usual, the quickest way to figure out a problem yourself is to ask the forum for help  ;-)